# Custom Query returns array, but I can't see it's elements

Tags: query, wpdb

guys! I have the following problem to solve - I am using Private Content plugin which divides users into categories. I need to show all posts from the category that the author is part of. I tried adding a custom query, which as tested returns the proper count of rows that are affected, but I can't get it to show the elements of the array (I have declared global $wpdb):

```
if (!current_user_can('administrator')) {

        //$groupcat is something like this string 'a:1:{i:0;s:2:\"23\";}';
        $groupcat = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT `categories` FROM 7NIaM6l_pc_users WHERE `wp_user_id` = 13", ARRAY_N);
    //Here I count the results and display them in the browser's console for check, which works fine
    $ac = count($groupcat);
    echo '<script>console.log("count ' . $ac . ' ")</script>';

//This part doesn't work.
echo '<script>console.log("First element: ' . groupcat[0] . ' ")</script>';
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment due to low reputation so sorry for posting this as an answer, but you are missing `$` (dollar sign) near `groupcat[0]`

Comment: I accidentally deleted it, but even with a $ it doesn't work

Comment: Yes, because you can not print an array like that. Try wrapping it into json_enocde, so it woud look like `json_encode( $groupcat[0] );`